# Weird behavior on item click

Tags: android, user-interface, onclick, buttonclick

I'm building an app that sends USSD commands to check for balance, etc. 
The apps acts weirdly when I try to launch activities from item click, here from image button: I have to touch two times to launch an activity. I don't know what is wrong.

Have a look at my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView accountView;
    ImageView activationsView;
    ImageView servicesView;
    ImageView othersView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

   public void openAccountView(View view){
        accountView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.accountView);
        accountView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AccountActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public void openActivationsView(View view){
        activationsView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activationsView);
        activationsView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivationsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public void openServicesView(View view){
        servicesView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.servicesView);
        servicesView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServicesActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public void openOthersView(View view){

    }


}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/layout_dashboard_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/c_dashboard_btn_quick_clean_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCB"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@color/c_main_back_ground_color"
            android:elevation="7dp"
            android:text="@string/check_balance"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLB"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@color/c_main_back_ground_color"
            android:elevation="7dp"
            android:text="@string/load_balance"
            tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@id/main_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/webview_ads"
        tools:ignore="UnknownIdInLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/layout_dashboard_scroll_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@id/dashboard_alert_section"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <include layout="@layout/dashboard_feature_tip_item" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@id/main_control_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="345">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@id/dashboard_progress_bar"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dashboard_clean_progess_mar_top"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/dashboard_progressbar_elevation"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:ignore="UselessParent"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dashboard_progress_clean_all_image_dimension"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_progress_clean_all_image_dimension"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:contentDescription=""
                        android:src="@drawable/btn_ram_checkbox"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/layout_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/c_main_back_ground_color">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/layout_account"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dashboard_feature_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_feature_layout_height"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dashboard_feature_middle_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dashboard_feature_leftmost_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dashboard_feature_middle_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dashboard_feature_leftmost_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dashboard_feature_top_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/dashboard_bg_selector"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/accountView"
                android:layout_width="130dip"
                android:layout_height="130dip"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:background="@color/checkbox_button_color"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/account"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:onClick="openAccountView"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/account" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/accountTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="@string/account"
                android:textColor="@color/body_text_color"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/accountView"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingEnd="2dip"
                android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                android:paddingRight="2dip"
                android:paddingStart="2dip"
                android:text="@string/account_detail"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/layout_activations"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dashboard_feature_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_feature_layout_height"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dashboard_feature_rightmost_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dashboard_feature_middle_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dashboard_feature_rightmost_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dashboard_feature_middle_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dashboard_feature_top_margin"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/layout_account"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout_account"
            android:background="@drawable/dashboard_bg_selector"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:elevation="@dimen/dashboard_feature_bg_elevation"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:onClick="openActivationsView"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activationsView"
                android:layout_width="130dip"
                android:layout_height="130dip"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/activations_packs"
                android:onClick="openActivationsView"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/activations" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/activationsView"
                android:elevation="7dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingEnd="2dip"
                android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                android:paddingRight="2dip"
                android:paddingStart="2dip"
                android:text="@string/activations_detail"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activationsTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="@string/activations_packs"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/layout_services"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dashboard_feature_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_feature_layout_height"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_account"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dashboard_feature_middle_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dashboard_feature_leftmost_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dashboard_feature_middle_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dashboard_feature_leftmost_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dashboard_feature_ram_security_top_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/dashboard_bg_selector"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:onClick="openServicesView"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/servicesTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:text="@string/services"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/servicesView"
                android:layout_width="130dip"
                android:layout_height="130dip"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/services"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/services" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/servicesView"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingEnd="2dip"
                android:paddingLeft="2dip"
                android:paddingRight="2dip"
                android:paddingStart="2dip"
                android:text="@string/services_detail"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@id/layout_others"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dashboard_feature_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_feature_layout_height"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_activations"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dashboard_feature_rightmost_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dashboard_feature_middle_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dashboard_feature_rightmost_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dashboard_feature_middle_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dashboard_feature_ram_security_top_margin"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/layout_services"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout_services"
            android:background="@drawable/dashboard_bg_selector"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:elevation="@dimen/dashboard_feature_bg_elevation"
            android:focusable="false"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
                android:text="@string/other_detail"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/otherView"
                android:layout_width="130dip"
                android:layout_height="130dip"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/other"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/help" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/otherTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:onClick="openOthersView"
                android:text="@string/other"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `openAccountView` method by onClick imageView by this:

`android:onClick="openAccountView"`

So, no need to add `onClicklistener` to your imageView.

Remove `onClicklistener` in `openAccountView`, Use the below code :

```
public void openAccountView(View view){
          Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AccountActivity.class);
          startActivity(i);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're already calling intent through onClick from xml. By also adding onClicklistener to your imageView in activity, you are requiring two clicks to call the intent. Hope this clear the things.

Comment: Don't worry, even the expert was once a noob !

Comment: I have another​ big problem. should I ask another question ? or I can ask it here

Comment: I think asking another question is the better idea.